# Как запретить вызовы API моего движка из потоков, отличных от главного?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Пишу небольшой 2D-движок, но решил упростить себе задачу - никакой потокобезопасности.

Весь движок, по сути - главный поток, в котором выполняется почти все, что нужно. Хотелось бы запретить вызовы API движка из потоков, отличных от главного. Но вот проблема в том, что я не знаю, как это делается.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы процесс завершался, если сделан вызов API из другого потока, при этом без большого изменения производительности?

Самый простой вариант - постоянно сверять `id` текущего потока с `id` главного. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что можно сделать проще.

Comment: Сверять id потоков хорошее решение, а если занести сверку под `assert`, то это никак не скажется на эффективности.

Comment: ИМХО обычно запретительством ни кто не занимается, а ограничиваются записью в документации типа «при вызове функций этой библиотеки не из главного потока определение не определено»... а для отладочных целей без `assert`'а (или ещё-какого макроса) не каждую входную точку скорей всего не обойтись...

Comment: `pthread_equal` смотреть [тут](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread.h.html)

Comment: @ffk особенно в релизе, где ассерты просто выпиливаются.

Comment: @Fat-Zer запретительством занимаются, и даже вполне часто. Как раз для целей отладки... Чтобы пользователь моего продукта не смог где-нибудь допустить ошибку. Кажется, тот же юнити не даёт вызывать апи из других потоков. Пожалуй, запилю ассерт-макро, который можно будет выключить при надобности

Comment: Завершаться без потери производительности, это как и главное зачем, вы же уже завершаетесь.

Comment: @älёxölüt так про это и речь, что не скажет на эффективности, в дебаге логику потоков проверил и зарелизился

Comment: @ffk при условии проверки всех ситуаций - да, но так бывает далеко не всегда. И получается, что в релизе приложение содержит больше проблемных мест, чем в отладке.

Answer (score 1):

На этапе компиляции никак это не проверить и не запретить. Для этапа выполнения ваш вариант вполне рабочий. Уж если вы приняли такое проектное решение, то постарайтесь сообщать об ошибках громко, понятно и сразу. Разработчик должен четко понимать что призошло и почему. Один раз сталкнется и либо уйдет, либо примет к сведению.

Посмотрите, в таких случаях, даже гранды предупреждают больше на словах. Например Qt, не позволяет выполнять код виджетов не в основном потоке. Как оно реагирует если разработчик ослушался. А никак, просто падает и все.

Comment: В Qt было ругательство в stderr, что виджеты могут быть созданы только в главном потоке. Насчет того, что падает сразу или нет -- не помню

Comment: Про stderr не знал. Падает не сразу, плохо там с этим